# Should the Object class ever be referenced in Java?

Tags: java, oop, object

I found this part of code:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = ...
```

It seems like the above should replace `Object` with some abstract class or interface that provides more structure for the value in the map. Is there any good reason to directly reference the `Object` class?

Comment: Your type parameter should be unspecific as is required by what you're storing and no less specific than that. If you are casting objects when you retrieve them from the map, you are not specific enough. Object has quite a few methods, so if all you do is call Object methods, having an Object value is fine

Comment: One use-case for `Map<String, Object>` might be a map of named locks. In that case, you might insert objects to use their implicit monitor locks `synchronized( map.get("my-lock-1") ) {`. In this case, it makes no sense to try to be more specific, since Object provides all the functionality you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API calls/responses (consuming/producing JSON) will always have a `String` key but the value may be text, numeric, boolean, array, or an object.

In the specific case of my project we use Spring MVC (which uses Jackson under the hood).  Our controllers always consume domain objects directly, e.g. an instance of the `User` class. Processing a `Map` with more than a couple of keys is a chore and prone to error.

We frequently return `Map<String, Object>` because responses almost always include metadata that is generated when the request is made. For example, a GET request made to `myapp/api/users` might return something like:

```js
{
  count: 2,
  timestamp: '2020-11-06T17:24:12.123Z',
  users: [
    {id: 1, firstName: 'Alice', lastName: 'Ackbar'},
    {id: 2, firstName: 'Boba', lastName: 'Bling'}
  ]
}
```

While the `users` property contains serialized `User` entities the remaining fields exist solely for the response. There is no point to creating a `UsersResponseEntity` class.